# VS Setup Project custom dialog to create config.xml

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

Do you know how to create the setup project with some custom dialogs before installing?

I need to add a config.xml with db data and some user specific data.

Is there a way to create something like this?

I found the option to add a new dialog with named "Textboxes (A)", there are 4 text inputs, but I need one more and the code behind to create the xml file.

Is there a way to do this?

I've seen some youtube videos, but nothing really helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for this in VS setup projects because there are no tools in it for creating custom dialogs, and no way to run code on (say) a button click on a dialog. Visual Studio setup projects don't expose all the features that are available in Windows Installer - you'd need WiX, InstallShield, Advanced Installer an so on.

Many people find it more convenient to do things like this when the app first runs. This is standard development using the usual debug tools, unlike custom actions called from an install.

Comment: I create a new Dialog with Orca.exe
You can export a default dialog, edit this with "orca dialog editor" and there you can bind dll files.
The Option to post parameter to a custom action is possible. I set some context values to pass the vars to my dll.

Here is a nice tutorial to do that, maybe you are interested ;)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18834/Create-custom-dialogs-for-use-in-your-Visual-Studi

Comment: The answer remains correct. There is no support in Visual Studio setup projects for custom dialogs. The fact that you can edit or create them with Orca doesn't change that fact!